# How to create name based on range

Tags: c++

I need to create name based on same ranges. I have below xml array which represents some ranges

```
<array>
 <range index="j" min="0" max="2" />
 <range index="k" min="1" max="6" />
 <range index = "l" min = "0" max = "1"/>
</array>
```

And these can be extended upto m,n,o etc.

So what I want is to be able to get the name in such a way that it should be as shown below :

> BASENAME_0_1_0  (means j = 0 , k = 1 , l= 0)
>
> BASENAME_0_1_0
>
> BASENAME_0_2_0
>
> BASENAME_0_2_0

As per max and min value the last element should be

> BASENAME_2_6_1 (means j = 2 , k =6 , l =1)

How can I write the c++ code to get "basename" like this independent of range limit ?

Comment: You can't. I would advise using a map.

Comment: @Fureeish I can store the value in map.
But how to iterate and construct the name?

Comment: Step 1: parse the XML into a data structure that maps letters to ranges, Step 2: Write a recursive function that generates all combinations alphabetically by letter. Which one are you having trouble with?

Comment: @botje recursive function that genreated all combinationas alphabetically by letter
can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `generate` function takes two parameters: a list of ranges to explore and the combination in the current path of the tree. If the list of ranges is empty, the combination is printed. If the list is not empty, the first range is explored (by means of a for loop over the range) and the recursive function is called for each possibility.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
struct range {
    int lo, hi;
};

using ranges = std::vector<range>;
using state = std::vector<int>;

void generate(ranges rs, state s={}) {
    if (rs.empty()) {
        for (auto i : s) {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } else {
        range first = rs[0];
        rs.erase(begin(rs));
        s.push_back(0);
        for (int i = first.lo; i <= first.hi; i++) {
            s.back() = i;
            generate(rs, s);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    range j {0, 2};
    range k {1, 6};
    range l {0, 1};
    generate({j,k,l});
}
```

Comment: s.push_back(0); 
Why you have write this statement?

Comment: To actually allocate space for the number whose range we are about to walk.